# Select Distinct rows based a particular column value in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have the following list `Lsit<Car> lstcarIP` it has the following data

```
ID  | Name | Year
0 - Zen    - 1990
1 - Alto   - 2003
3 - Zen    - 2004
4 - Santro - 2000
5 - Alto   - 2003
```

Irrespective of the ID and year the output `list<Car> lstFinal` should have

```
   ID  | Name | Year
    0 - Zen    - 1990
    1 - Alto   - 2003 
    4 - Santro - 2000
```

or

```
 ID  | Name | Year 
    3 - Zen    - 2004
    4 - Santro - 2000
    5 - Alto   - 2003
```

ie If the Name occurs again then only one entry should be added to the `list<Car> lstFinal` . I tried using `LastorDefault` or `GroupBy`

```
 lstFinal= lstcarIP.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                             .SelectMany(g => g)
                             .ToList<Car>();
```

But couldnt get proper result. Could you correct me and point my mistake.
Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Does your result only include Zen and Alto?  If so, it's because of `g.Count() > 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just `GroupBy`, and then get `First`

```
 lstFinal = lstcarIP.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList<Car>();
```